# How to select the most optimal hyperparameter in grid-search cross validation if the process is repeated X (i.e. 3) times?

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation, svm, hyperparameter

I have some data (total N = 100,000 rows). I randomly selected 10% from it to become the validation set to help identify the best set of hyperparameters. To do that I am conducting grid search based on 5-fold cross-validation.

I understand in `scikit-learn`, I can simply obtain the best parameter set as an output. But I want to repeat the 5-fold cross-validation grid search for 3 times.

The grid search options are as follows for `SVC`:

```
C:  0.001,  0.01,   0.1
tol:    0.001,  0.01,   0.1
class_weight:   None,   balanced
```

Say, after repeating it 3 times, the followings are the best parameter setting for each iteration:

```
                         Accuracy   C        tol    class_weight
Best in iteration 1          0.8    0.1     0.01    None
Best in iteration 2         0.75    0.001   0.001   balanced
Best in iteration 3         0.78    0.001   0.001   None
```

What is the best way to select the final (most optimal) parameter set? Do I simply choose Iteration #1 since its accuracy is better than the other two?

Or because their accuracy are fairly similar, can I make a case to choose 0.001 for `tol` since it appears more often than 0.01? If to be based on highest frequency for each parameter, then I will be choosing `C=0.001, tol=0.001, and class_weight=None`. Or would basing it on frequency be a bad idea as parameters relate and influence each other for the algorithm to work optimally?

Comment: I think *most optimal* is superfluous as *optimal* is already the best there is.

Comment: Well, it's just semantics. Each iteration is supposed to generate an optimal parameter set, I want to distinguish the final chosen set derived from these optimal sets, so it's arbitrary called "most optimal".